# MySQL - Combine duplicate conditions on both sides of OR statement

Tags: mysql

I've somehow become even more incompetent since leaving university last April. I have what I think should be a very easy task: I have a lot of duplicate conditions on both sides of this `OR` MySQL statement. How do I combine the conditions that apply to both sides of the `OR`?

```
WHERE (
  v_xr_drives.driveisvirtual LIKE "%1%" /*If it's a virtual drive...*/
  AND
  eventblacklist.`eventblacklistid` > 0
  AND
  (
    eventlogs.source LIKE 'disk'
  )
  AND
  timegen > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 day)
  AND
  eventlogs.message NOT LIKE "%during a paging operation%"
  AND
  eventlogs.message NOT LIKE "%controller error%" /*...then I don't want rows returned for drive controller errors.*/
)
OR
(
  v_xr_drives.driveisvirtual LIKE "%0%" /*But if it's a physical drive...*/
  AND
  eventblacklist.`eventblacklistid` > 0
  AND
  (
    eventlogs.source LIKE 'disk'
  )
  AND
  timegen > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 day)
  AND
  eventlogs.message NOT LIKE "%during a paging operation%"
  /*...then I still want rows returned for drive controller errors (thus omitting the 'NOTLIKE "%controller error%"' condition from above*/
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just AND them with the result of the OR:

```
WHERE 
((
  v_xr_drives.driveisvirtual LIKE "%1%" /*If it's a virtual drive...*/
  AND
  eventlogs.message NOT LIKE "%controller error%" /*...then I don't want rows returned for drive controller errors.*/
)
OR
(
  v_xr_drives.driveisvirtual LIKE "%0%" /*But if it's a physical drive...*/
))
AND
eventblacklist.`eventblacklistid` > 0
AND
(
  eventlogs.source LIKE 'disk'
)
AND
timegen > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 day)
AND
eventlogs.message NOT LIKE "%during a paging operation%"
```